# Не корректно работает функция

Tags: jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста почему не корректно работает данная функция. Она добавляет класс только после того как вручную изменишь ширину экрана, а если ширина экрана уже меньше 640px, то после обновления страницы класс добавляется только если опять изменишь ширину экрана.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() {
        if ($(window).width() <= '640'){
            $('.header__navigation-img').on('click', function(){
                $('.header__nav').toggleClass('header__nav-active');
            })
        } else {
            $('.header__nav').removeClass('header__nav-active');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: У вас проверка ширины экрана находится в функции `resize`, а вам нужно, чтобы эта проверка была и в функции `ready`

Comment: Спасибо, исправил, работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.header__navigation-img').on('click', function() {
        if ($(window).width() <= 640) {
            $('.header__nav').toggleClass('header__nav-active');
        }
    });

    $(window).resize(function() {
        if ($(window).width() > 640) {
            $('.header__nav').removeClass('header__nav-active');
        }
    });

    $(window).resize();
    $('.header__navigation-img').click();

});
```

Comment: А зачем последние 2 строки?

Comment: @MarianVytak Чтобы класс добавился или убрался после загрузки страницы.

Comment: Понял, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Забить бы всё в переменные по хорошему:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var $window = $(window);
    var $nav = $('.header__nav');
    var $navImage = $('.header__navigation-img');

    $navImage.on('click',function(e){
        if ($window.width() <= 640) { $nav.toggleClass('header__nav-active'); }
    }).trigger('click');

    $window.resize(function() {
        if ($window.width() > 640) { $nav.removeClass('header__nav-active'); }
    }).trigger('resize');

});
```